# ColumnTransformer implementation in sklearn doesn't have a fit method defined, it just automatically calls fit_transform?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

My data grows to a size too large to handle in memory when I'm applying a Sliding Window Algorithm, but it is small enough that I can call **ColumnTransformer's fit method** without any issues. Thus, my desired workflow is:

1. Fit the entire data for the `MinMaxScaler()`
2. Transform batches of the data for the `SlidingWindowAlgorithm()`

Problem is that it seems that the fit method doesn't exist in `ColumnTransformer`, looking at the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0fb307bf39bbdacd6ed713c00724f8f871d60370/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py#L474) shows this:

```
def fit(self, X, y=None):
    # we use fit_transform to make sure to set sparse_output_ (for which we
    # need the transformed data) to have consistent output type in predict
    self.fit_transform(X, y=y)
    return self
```

I don't understand their reasoning (don't know the purpose of `sparse_output_`).

Is there a way that I can fit my data without transforming? I'm not using a sparse matrix for what it's worth, just a regular `numpy` one.

Here is my code, `data_in` is set to give you 500MBs of RAM. And as you increase the value of `window_size` an incredible spike in RAM will be detected. (I need `window_size` to be 60).

```
## Part 0: Starting
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

data_in = np.random.rand(10*10**6,7) # This will take 500MB of RAM
window_size = 1 # Change this value!

## Part 1: Creating Transformers!
class SlidingWindowX(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, window_size):
        self.window_size = window_size

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        '''
        Creates a sliding window over an input that has the shape of
        (rows, features) for X
        '''
        if X.ndim == 1:
            X = X.reshape(-1, 1)

        row_size = X.shape[0]
        X_out = np.zeros((row_size-2*self.window_size, 1))

        for j in range(X.shape[1]):
            for i in range(self.window_size):
                idx1 = i
                idx2 = row_size-2*self.window_size+i
                X_out = np.concatenate((X_out, X[idx1:idx2, j].reshape(-1, 1)), axis=1)

        return X_out[:, 1:]

## Part 2: Making pipelines!
attribs_elec = np.arange(0, 7)


pipe_elec = Pipeline([
    ('min-max', MinMaxScaler()),
    ('window', SlidingWindowX(window_size))
])


pipe_full = ColumnTransformer([
    ("elec", pipe_elec, attribs_elec),
])

pipe_full.fit(data_in)
```

Comment: Can you post more code of your pipeline?

Comment: @SameerZahid I just added it, `## Part 1` is where my transformer's are defined and `## Part 2` is where the pipeline is.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question

> Is there a way that I can fit my data without transforming?

Yes, you can just call the `fit_transform()` method with your data and it will fit the `ColumnTransformer`. Your data will not be transformed, since the input data remains unchanged and the transformed data is only returned via the output (which you don't have to save).

Since your code can not be run as you mentioned (lack of data), I have this example here from the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html#sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.fit_transform):

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import Normalizer
ct = ColumnTransformer(
    [("norm1", Normalizer(norm='l1'), [0, 1]),
     ("norm2", Normalizer(norm='l1'), slice(2, 4))])
X = np.array([[0., 1., 2., 2.],
              [1., 1., 0., 1.]])
```

Now you can call `fit_transform()`:

```
ct.fit_transform(X)
```

which returns the transformed data:

```
array([[0. , 1. , 0.5, 0.5],
       [0.5, 0.5, 0. , 1. ]])
```

But this is not being stored and therefore the data (X) remains the same:

```
X
```

Output:

```
array([[0., 1., 2., 2.],
       [1., 1., 0., 1.]])
```

Comment: My issue isn't with my input data being transformed, it is with the unnecessary spike of RAM caused by the `fit` method when it is calling the `fit_transform` method. I updated my question to include runable code. Try increasing `window_size` while monitoring your RAM and the time it needs to execute.